# GitHub pages only showing ReadMe file in React App

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I'm trying to host my React app into GitHub but only the Readme file is shown.
Github repo: https://github.com/vivekbhardwaj-1201/invictus.git
website:https://vivekbhardwaj-1201.github.io/invictus/

Comment: I don't see a `gh-pages` branch in your repository.

Comment: Just follow the procedure described here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#github-pages